# Size of a structure

Tags: assembly

Technically, the size of a structure is the amount of bytes that need the variables of the structure.

For example, if I use the next standard structure:

```
; building the sockaddr_in struct
push 0  ; INADDR_ANY
push WORD 0x672b ; port 11111
push WORD 2 ; AF_INET
```

2 tutorials I'm reading say: sizeof(struct sockaddr) = 16 (socklen_t)

But I only see 1 dword and 2 words = 8 bytes.
8 bytes, no 16. What am I doing bad? The tutorials don't use macros, they put the imm value and no more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**See this:**

```
sockaddr_in STRUCT
sin_family DW   ?
sin_port DW ?
sin_addr DB ?
DB  ?
DB  ?
DB  ?
sin_zero DB 8 DUP (?)
sockaddr_in ENDS
```

Comment: Where did you found this? In http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/sockaddr_inman.html no, for example :/

Comment: @rob in your link the struct also adds up to 16 bytes